# Should + (plus) sign work for Routes in Azure Functions 2

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We have migrated an app to Azure Functions 2, and we have the following route setup:

```
"testABC/{testA}/{testB}"
```

in the azure function code we have:

```
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(HttpRequestMessage req, string testA, string testB, TraceWriter log)
{
  var res = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
  res.Content = new StringContent($"{testA} - {testB}");
  return res;
}
```

When I run this url: https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/testABC/74aff65f-5f46-4e28-838b-3093d18a3552/test
it works

However if I add a plus sign it does not work: When I run this url: https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/testABC/74aff65f-5f46-4e28-838b-3093d18a3552/te+st
It gives this error:

*The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.*

Adding a space instead of a plus works too.  This isn't an issue with Azure Functions 1.  What am I missing here?

Comment: By "route setup", do you mean that you are using an Azure Function Proxy? There are also route templates, although then your url would look more like ".net/api/testABC" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#customize-the-http-endpoint

Comment: Hi Marie, I am not using any proxies - just the standard Route Template.  Its working fine - except when there is a + in the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

It turns out [allowDoubleEscaping="true" missing](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/commit/d1c9b7167e06870eee2a39a8f753341c74a5ba06) in v2 . It should have been fixed since runtime 2.0.12265, right now I see 2.0.12275 on my side.

---

Got same error on my side, but everything works locally so I doubt there could be some server request filter settings on Azure which restrict plus sign. Have opened [an issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3786) to track this problem.

Comment: Thanks Jerry - that was going to be my next step; but I just thought that it couldn't be possible that this overlooked and that I was doing something wrong.

Comment: @tank104 We probably did everything we could. As mentioned in the issue, I can use `+` in url in v1 on Azure site as you have found, both v1 and v2 work locally as well. The inconsistency should prove that we didn't do anything wrong. It's possible that there are some settings to check but I didn't find any clue in Azure Functions document. So I assume it's time we move to the next step.